# C++ SDL Breaking out of while loop

Tags: c++, c

I've been messing around with C++ SDL for a few days now and I've come across an interesting problem.

```
SDL_Event event1;
while(SDL_WaitEvent(&event1))
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < MainMenuOptions.size();i++)
    {
        if(event1.button.x > MainMenuOptions.at(i).GetX() && event1.button.x < (MainMenuOptions.at(i).GetX() + MainMenuOptions.at(i).GetWidth())  
        && event1.button.y > MainMenuOptions.at(i).GetY()  && event1.button.y < (MainMenuOptions.at(i).GetY() + MainMenuOptions.at(i).GetHeight()))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use break in the for loop its going to break out of the for loop instead of the while loop. How would I break out the while loop instead without using the goto statement? (the goto statement is bad programming, I heard)

Comment: You heard bad. **`goto` is excellent**.

Comment: @cnicutar I hope to dog you're joking.

Comment: @cnicutar http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I posted that in my now deleted post. All jokes aside, after some time in the Linux kernel I can vouch `goto` is an excellent tool, providing for simple, deeply elegant code.

Comment: @JamWaffles http://web.archive.org/web/20090320002214/http://www.ecn.purdue.edu/ParaMount/papers/rubin87goto.pdf

Comment: @cnicutar: The Linux kernel is all C. In C++, given RAII (no need to jump to cleanup code), inlining (just put the code in a function and return from that) and other C++ goodies, `goto` is never really needed in C++, and rarely ever more elegant/maintainable than one of the constructs that replaced it. (And by "rarely ever" I refer to the fact that, in 20 years of C++, I can't remember a single case where that was true, but admit that I might have forgotten one or two.)

Comment: @sbi You do have a point but I dislike generalized statements "X feature is BAD". Your "never really needed" seems a bit more reasonable :-)

Comment: @cnicutar: If better alternatives exist for all cases where one might use a feature, isn't then the feature "worse" than the alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's another answer to that, and I think I should say it before everyone will downvote me.
Using a variable is certainly a "good" way to do it. However, the creating additional variable just to jump out of the loop seems a bit of overkill, right?

So yes, this time `goto` is perfect solution. It's perfectly clear what you are doing with it, you are not using another variable and the code remains short, maintainable and readable.

The statement *goto is bad practice* is mostly a remnant of the BASIC times, when it was quite the only way of changing code flow. However, now we "know better", and saying that the `goto` or any other construction is bad, just doesn't cut it. It can be bad *for one particular problem* you are trying to solve with it (and it's the case with most of the problems that people try to solve with goto). However, given the right circumstances  (like here) it's OK. I don't want to start a debate here, of course. Goto is like a very powerful tool (sledgehammer, for example). It has its uses and you can't say a tool is totally bad; it's the user using it in the wrong way.

Comment: Guess you have a point. This makes me wonder, though, when should I use goto and when should I not?

Comment: Well, the double- or multiple- nested loop is one of the examples when it's OK. Generally you should use common sense. If you feel that the code is clear and understandable, it's probably OK. However, bear in mind that code changes, and you have to be able to accomodate for that. Try changing the requirements of given code part and play in your mind - what you will have to change? How much the code structure will change? Then you will be able to decide.

Comment: Thank you for your short and constructive answer.

Comment: TL; DR - there are really only few situations in modern C++ that goto is really needed.

Comment: Any `goto` is always worse than a solution using the structural statements the language provides: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12034773/140719 In more than twenty years of doing C++, I have yet to see a case where a `goto` is necessary, and I have seen _very_ few where it leads to more easily maintainable code than the alternatives. (That is different in C, BTW, where there's no RAII and other helpful constructs. Often, if someone insists on `goto` being necessary in C++, they are actually writing C code disguised as C++.)

Comment: Provided someone is fluent enough in more complicated language constructs, I totally agree with you.

Comment: Since when is writing and calling a function more complicated as using goto?

Comment: +1: This is _the_ correct and canonical answer. It is _precisely equivalent_ to the hypothetical `break 2;` statement that you'd, I'm sure, have absolutely no qualms about using. **`continue` and `break` already jump, so why are you afraid of `goto`?** I wish only that I could +1 a second time, as bonus points for being brave enough to speak out against the rampaging hordes of baseless mantra.

Answer (score 11):

The common solution is to put this stuff into its own function and return from that:

```
inline SDL_Event do_it()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_WaitEvent(&event))
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < MainMenuOptions.size(); ++i)
            if(/*...*/)
                return event;
    return event; // or whatever else suits, I know too little about your code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a variable to indicate the need to exit:

```
bool exit_program = false;

while( !exit_program && SDL_WaitEvent(&event1) )
{
    for( /* ... */ )
    {
        exit_program = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant mate I shud've thought of that!

Answer (score 4):

First point: IMO, you're trying to wrap too much up into a single place, and ending up with something that's fairly difficult to understand -- somebody has to read through that entire long set of comparisons before they can understand any of what this is supposed to accomplish at all.

Second point: using an explicit loop to iterate over a standard collection is usually a mistake -- and this is no exception. The standard library already has an algorithm to accomplish the same basic thing as your loop. It's better to use that than write it again yourself.

```
template <class T>
bool in_range(T a, T b, T c) { 
    return (a > b) && (a < b+c);
}

class in_rect {
   point p;
public:
   in_rect(point const &p) : p(p) {}

   // Not sure of the type of objects in MainMenuOptions, so just T for now.
   // 
   bool operator()(T const &m) {
       return in_range(p.x, m.GetX(), m.GetWidth()) 
           && in_range(p.y, m.GetY(), m.GetHeight());
   }
};

SDL_Event event1;

while (SDL_WaitEvent(&event1))
    if (std::any_of(MainMenuOptions.begin(), MainMenuOptions.end(),
                    in_rect(event1.button))      
        break;
```

Once we fix the other problems, there's simply no longer any need (or even use) for the `goto`. We haven't taken any steps explicitly intended to remove it, but when the other problems have been fixed (especially, replacing the loop with an appropriate algorithm), the use for it has disappeared.

I suppose I should preemptively comment on the increase in the total number of lines of code: yes, there are more lines of code. What of it? If we really wanted to, we could use the same basic approach, but instead of defining `in_rect` and `in_range`, we'd basically just take the condition from the original `if` statement and stuff it into a lambda. While I'm *very* happy that lambdas have been added to C++, in this case I'm not excited about using it. It would get rid of the `goto`, but in general the code would be almost as unreadable as it started out.

Simply put, the number of lines isn't a good way to measure much of anything.

Answer (score -1):

A solution without additional variable and `goto`:

```
while(SDL_WaitEvent(&event1))
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < MainMenuOptions.size();i++)
    {
        if(/* ... */)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i < MainMenuOptions.size())
        break;
}
```

Comment: Wait. You somehow think that removing a variable is good? You introduced __evil__ code duplication, for no reason. This is inviting bugs when the condition needs to be changed. (Not to mention this breaks down if the condition expression has sideeffects.)

Comment: @sehe: No, I don't think that removing some variables is always good. And probably I wouldn't have done it this way. After the two answers, I thought about a third solution. But I understand your concerns, yet I think (with your comment) it's a good example, how not to do it, so I leave it as it stands.